# Kubuntu: suspend / lid closure on 1st gen Thinkpad Yoga breaks trackpad

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad, lenovo-laptop, kubuntu

After fresh boot / reboot the trackpad works as expected, using SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad driver. However, after lid closure (which leads to a system suspend), the functionality breaks inconsistently, in a way that is hard to reproduce.

Failure profile one: two-finger scrolling has a brief lag before starting, and is much slower than usual.

Failure profile two: two-finger scrolling no longer works, and three-finger scrolling does.

The second profile really, really confuses me, as none of the settings have changed (two-finger scrolling set to enabled, three fingers aren't).

Below is the xinput, which remains unchanged before and after the lid closure event.

```
rory@rory-ThinkPad-S1-Yoga:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

System info:

```
rory@rory-ThinkPad-S1-Yoga:~$ uname -a
Linux rory-ThinkPad-S1-Yoga 4.15.0-54-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 24 10:55:24 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Hardware Info:

```
rory@rory-ThinkPad-S1-Yoga:~$ lshw -short
H/W path         Device     Class          Description
======================================================
                            system         20C0S0UG00 (LENOVO_MT_20C0_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad S1 Yoga)
/0                          bus            20C0S0UG00
/0/0                        processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz
/0/0/2                      memory         32KiB L1 cache
/0/0/3                      memory         256KiB L2 cache
/0/0/4                      memory         3MiB L3 cache
/0/1                        memory         32KiB L1 cache
/0/5                        memory         8GiB System Memory
/0/5/0                      memory         4GiB Chip DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
/0/5/1                      memory         4GiB Chip DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
/0/44                       memory         128KiB BIOS
/0/100                      bridge         Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller
/0/100/2                    display        Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
/0/100/3                    multimedia     Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
/0/100/14                   bus            8 Series USB xHCI HC
/0/100/14/0      usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/4               communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/14/0/5               input          Touchscreen
/0/100/14/0/6               multimedia     Integrated Camera
/0/100/14/1      usb3       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/16                   communication  8 Series HECI #0
/0/100/1b                   multimedia     8 Series HD Audio Controller
/0/100/1c                   bridge         8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1
/0/100/1c.2                 bridge         8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3
/0/100/1c.2/0    wlp4s0     network        Wireless 7260
/0/100/1c.3                 bridge         8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4
/0/100/1c.3/0               generic        RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/1d                   bus            8 Series USB EHCI #1
/0/100/1d/1      usb1       bus            EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1d/1/1               bus            USB hub
/0/100/1d/1/1/7             input          ST_SENSOR_HUB
/0/100/1f                   bridge         8 Series LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2                 storage        8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
/0/100/1f.3                 bus            8 Series SMBus Controller
/0/2             scsi0      storage        
/0/2/0.0.0       /dev/sda   disk           180GB INTEL SSDSC2BF18
/0/2/0.0.0/1     /dev/sda1  volume         500MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/2/0.0.0/2     /dev/sda2  volume         34GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/2/0.0.0/3     /dev/sda3  volume         132GiB Extended partition
/0/2/0.0.0/3/5   /dev/sda5  volume         132GiB EXT4 volume
/1                          power          45N1705
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is awkward. Although I had done a full `sudo apt upgrade` and `sudo apt update`, this was actually fixed by just re-installing my synaptics driver. It's unclear why this wouldn't have been auto updated, but then I'm not deeply knowledgeable about ubuntu package management. This was the command which fixed it:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Credit: https://askubuntu.com/a/1035863